# Regular Expression (Regex) for only digits(0-9) followed by dot

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex for only digits(0-9) followed by dot. This can continue up to 4 times. The trick is it is not necessary to be continued.

For example:

```
1234 is OK  
1234.1234 is OK  
1234.1234.1234 is OK  
1234.1234.1234.1234 is OK
```

NOT OK:

```
asdf NOT OK  
1234.. NOT OK 
1234..1234 NOT OK  
1234,-/etc. NOT OK  
123asd NOT OK  
1234.1234asd NOT OK
```

Comment: Please tag this with the language that you are using - regex syntax differs between languages

Comment: This is not that difficult and you should try something by yourself. SO is not a code delivery service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, this should work:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,3}$
```

Comment: +1 although I'd personally use `\d` over `[0-9]` giving `^\d+(\.\d+){0,3}$ `!

Comment: Yes, that's neater but I wasn't sure if `\d` is universally recognised or not, and there is no mention of what language OP is using

Comment: Very true, `[0-9]` is more universal.

Comment: yes, this is exactly the solution for my case; thank you :)

Comment: @user1734938: Next time wait a few hours before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is this for C#?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+(\.\d+){0,3}$");
```

Comment: no, "^\d+(\.\d+)*$" is much more close to my case but thanks anyway

Comment: @user1734938: Actually it isn't. You wanted up to three repetitions, but the asterisk versions allow up to infinite repetitions.

Comment: @phresnel: True.[] were not really needed. Fixed it.

Comment: @phresnel: user1734938 seemed a bit confused. He said M42's answer is correct. He commented here and he commented on his answer and then accepted codebox's answer.

Comment: @TCM: ... of course after he had already accepted another answer :P

Answer (score 2):

how about  this one:

```
^\d+(\.\d+){0,3}$
```

Comment: This allows too many (unlimited) secondary groups!

Comment: @M42: 1234.1234.1234.1234. is counted as valid.

Comment: that is almost what i wanted, i can reshape from here; thank you so much!

Comment: @Stevo3000: You're right, I misread the question. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I agree with the accepted answer. I cannot make the accepted answer work.

As far as I understand it the accepted answer is matching:-

> `^`                 start of string
>
> `[0-9]+`           one or more digits 0 thru 9 this can also be represented short hand \d
>
> `(`               start of repetition
>
> `\.`              a single period (escaped to ensure not treated as wild card)
>
> `[0-9]+`          one or more digits 0 thru 9 this can also be represented short hand \d
>
> `)`               end of repetition
>
> `{0,3}`           repeated 0 or 3 times
>
> `$`               end of string

therefore we might match for example

1234.12.123456789.1234 or

1234.12 or

123.1.234 or

1

I may be misunderstanding something but this does not meet the specification give by the SO's example.

Shouldn't this be

```
^\d{4}(\.\d{4}){0,3}$
```

i.e.

> `^`                 start of string
>
> `\d{4}`           four digits
>
> `(`               start of repetition
>
> `\.`              a single period (escaped to ensure not treated as wild card)
>
> `\d{4}`          4 digits
>
> `)`               end of repetition
>
> `{0,3}`           repeated 0 or 3 times
>
> `$`               end of string

This will match

1234 or

1234.1234 or

1234.1234.1234 or

1234.1234.1234.1234

which I read as complying with the requirement.